# Combobox eats blank spaces, contents appear unaligned

Tags: java, arrays, swing, format, jcombobox

I'm tryng to populate a jcombobox with an ip address, a port and a debug status (true or false) all in one line. If the length of the items are different they appear unorganized in the jcomboxbox. I would like it to be aligned.

Output in console (and desired output in jcombobox):

```
   136.18.151.1   8735   true
  200.200.20.21  32310   true
  300.34.30.100   2138  false
 400.400.400.10  31230  false
```

Output in jcomboxbox:

```
   136.18.151.1   8735   true
    200.200.20.21  32310  true
  300.34.30.100   2138  false
   400.400.400.100  31230  false
```

Basically I'm reading from an XML file and then i save each item in their respective listarrays.

```
public List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> portList = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> debugList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then i get each item from the same index from the arrays, put it into a string and then join the strings and put the joined string in a regular string array.

```
public class myJAXB {

 public String[] populateArray() {

        int size = ipList.size();
        String[] connsList = new String[size];
        String tempIp, tempPort, tempDebug;


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            tempIp = ipList.get(i);

            // here is the default jdk method (has not worked)
            tempIp = String.format("15%s", tempIp);

            // here im using the apache commons lib (has not worked)
            tempIp = StringUtils.leftPad(tempIp,15);

            //this is a method I created (has not worked)
            tempIp = formatString(tempIp, 'i');

            //same steps for the portList and debugList.. omitted for brevity 

            //save strings to string array, I suspect the error could be here? When joining strings maybe?
            connsList[i] = tempIp + tempPort +  tempDebug;

            //print to console to check output
            System.out.println("" + connsList[i]);
        }


        return connsList;
    }
}
```

This is my formatString method

```
public class myJAXB {

 public String formatString(String string, char type) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //desired length of string
        int padnum = 0;

        //actual length of string
        int length=0;

        //if ip address
        if (type == 'i') {
            padnum = 15;
        }

        //if port or debug
        if (type == 'p' || type == 'd') {
            padnum = 7;
        }

        length = string.length();

        char[] pad = new char[padnum - length];

        //fill char array with empty space
        Arrays.fill(pad, ' ');

        return sb.append(pad).append(string).toString();
    }

}
```

And finally my call to create and populate the jcombobox

```
jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(jax.populateArray()));
```

Have also tried to make it align when creating the jcombobox but has not worked either..

```
// ((JLabel)jComboBox1.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);        
// ((JLabel)jComboBox1.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

I've noticed while debugging that the spaces are indeed inserted, the contents of the final string array are the way the should be but when they are put into the jcombobox it changes!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Use a JTable -- the right tool for the job, not a JComboBox.

Comment: Second the use of the JTable, and discourage the use of parallel arrays (that's what classes are for)

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response, I'm trying to avoid using a jTable since I don't need to see all the contents at first glance. Also to save space in my gui. I don't really need to interact with the combobox either, it's just there to show the list of items in a compact way

Comment: use MonoSpaced Font for JComponents

Comment: @mKorbel your solution worked! Thank you so much! If I could I'd mark your comment as the answer but I don't see any option to do so.